# Sometimes intent returns null

Tags: android

In login activity,I have following lines:

```
public final static String APPV = "com.impact.pack.APPV";

private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(APPVT,getAppVersion(context));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
}

private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
```

I am calling `startMainActivity` method from `onCreate` in Login Activity.

And this is my main activity's `onCreate` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
APPV=intent.getIntExtra(LoginActivity.APPVT,1);
Log.w("App version:",""+APPV);
```

My app version is `17` but sometimes `Log.w` is writing `1` for `App version`.I mean sometimes intent is getting null value.But why ? How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Are you ever hitting the runtime exception? Also are there other activities in the project or are you only testing with these?

Comment: No,never getting runtime exception.

Comment: I have just 2 activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the function onNewIntent as stated in the document for FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

---

FURTHER

I suspect this is is happening because instead of starting a new activity your code is actually resurrecting an old activity from the stack and the intent is not being properly delivered.

Also since the appVersion will not change you might consider saving it in your AppPrefs and then just accessing it from there. Much more reliable and a whole lot cleaner than passing through intents. :)

Comment: Can you move your appVersion to AppPrefs? It is circumventing the issue but its also better practice in this case.